# Form generation and validation similar to Symfony2 in java?

Tags: java, spring, forms, symfony

I'm currently working on a web project written in java. Coming from Symfony2 background, I'm looking for a way to handle web form generation and validation similar to Symfony's [Form](http://symfony.com/doc/2.5/book/forms.html) component. What this component does is generate a form based on an `Entity` and validate it upon submission. There is also a possibility to have nested/embedded sub-forms.

Is there a similar library/framework I could use in java to achieve the same results? Is there a way to do this with [Spring](https://spring.io/), perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible, see:
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields

http://www.bincsoft.com/blog/thymeleaf-and-lists-in-forms/

[Thymeleaf and #fields.hasErrors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33715938/thymeleaf-and-fields-haserrors)

Comment: That seems to unfortunately only scratch the surface of what Symfony's form component can do and still requires boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

At the time I posted this question there wasn't really a good answer to this question. It seems that now you can use [Spring Validation Form](https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/) which is quite similar to Symfony's Form Validation.